# Can I Create Two Entity Framework Contexts That Have The Exact Same Model For Both Contexts?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have two separate sets of tables in the same database that model the exact same data but in different states. One is a live state, and the other is a staging state (not test). I am trying to create a model that will allow me to choose which datasource/datacontext to use at runtime, but they must both have the same model.

```
public TestObject GetTestObject(string testNum, string Environment)
{
    IDataContext context = DataContextFactory.GetContext(Environment);
    TestObject t = (from test in context.Orderable
                         where test.TestNumber == testNum
                         select test).FirstOrDefault();
    return t;
}
```

Obviously, based on the code above, if the Environment is Staging, I pull from a set of tables. If the Environment is Live, then I pull from a different set of tables.

So, normally with EF, I will get two separate models with different names. If I try give them the same name I get errors stating that there is already an object with that name in the project.

I have recently looked into my own POCO to consume the database, but have not been able to connect the dots to create a solution.

EDIT: Changed from "Two datasources" to "Two sets of tables in the same database". This was obviously confusing, my apologies.

Comment: This is what connectionstrings are for.  You change the connection string to point to the staging database or the production database.

Comment: @MystereMan They are in the same database. It is two sets of 4 views in the same database.

Comment: Then it's not the same data model, it's a different data model that just happens to have the same definitions.

Comment: So are you then saying that this differentiation that you're making means that my requirements are impossible? The data structure for both sets of tables are exactly the same. I was hoping that I could interact with both of them the same.

Comment: The table names are different.  Thus, they are different enties.  It's *possible* to muck around and make something work, but you would be fighting EF the whole way, and probably have all kinds of subtle problems happen along the way.  It just won't be worth it.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Want to throw that in an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible?  Probably.  Is it a good idea?  No.  Will it take more time than it's worth to make it work?  Most likely.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, you really don't need two contexts.

You just need to swap out the connection string that is used when you instantiate your context at runtime. That will allow you to point your context at either the production or staging database.

Comment: They are in the same database.

Comment: @Quickhorn - Then the contexts aren't going to be identical. The table names are going to be different. Is there a reason each environment doesn't have its own database?

Comment: Because the original design of the database is old and not well-defined. The contexts aren't going ot be identical, but the model I want them to consume I want to be identical, so I can use a single linq statement for each context rather than 2 completely identical sets of linq statements.